# I am not able to invoke a simple rest controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

This is my controller code, and I am trying to invoke it using a url http://localhost:8089/webservroj/UserInfo?UserId=123 but it gives an error 404.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cas.models.UserInformationModel;

@RestController

@RequestMapping("/")

public class  UserInformationController {

UserInformationModel jon =new UserInformationModel(19, "jon", "LA");

@RequestMapping(value="UserInfo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public UserInformationModel getUserInformation(@RequestParam int UserId){   
return jon;
}}
```

Comment: What about `http://localhost:8089/UserInfo?UserId=123`

Comment: Did you set port 8089 at configuration ?

Comment: yeah, 8089 is the port set in the configuration

Comment: Like BrunoDM suggested /webservroj/ might be not part of your mapping. Try without it.

Comment: That is the name of my project

Comment: Could you share your app error log?

Comment: eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130530-1430
java.version=1.8.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Mon Jun 05 05:42:30 CDT 2017
Cannot find a free socket for the debugger
@fiskra

Comment: When you face with a problem on your app, looking at logs is the first thing we should do. I think it seems your problem is about windows and eclipse. So you should google your error first and solve the **socket** problem. And please share your error log on your post and update it, not as a comment.